# select2 not working inside fooftable

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2, footable

Why select2 is not working inside a footable?

I want to put a select2 in a fooftable cell.

```
<td>
   <select class="form-control" id="_products">                                           
      <option value="1">Test Product 1</option>
      <option value="2">Test Product 2</option>
      <option value="3">Test Product 3</option>
      <option value="4">Test Product 4</option>
   </select>
</td>
```

Here is a jsfiddle with the example.

https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/54155/

I am using jquery-footable 3.1.6 and select2 4.0.6 rc1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call select2 after the footable is rendered.

```
$('.footable').footable({},function(){
    $('select.form-control').select2();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/54223/